# How to convert TOR v3 private/public keys in Node.js using crypto library

Tags: node.js, tor

I have private/public keys (files `hs_ed25519_secret_key` and `hs_ed25519_public_key`) generated by Tor. My goal is to convert them to [`KeyObject`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_keyobject) in Node.js, but I cannot extract keys from them.

When I open the file (e.g. `hs_ed25519_secret_key`), I see this:

```
== ed25519v1-secret: type0 ==8����+�Z�Y���DsЄ�_�K���k�h��z�z|�<ʾ'�Q��:������`�D'��
```

I guess they used `base64` encoding. So, I tried to open the file with:

```js
import fs from "fs";
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync("./hs_ed25519_secret_key", "base64");
```

and got the following output:

```
PT0gZWQyNTUxOXYxLXNlY3JldDogdHlwZTAgPT0AAAAYC++/vXtY77+977+977+9UWlCTGXvv73vv73vv70efu+/ve+/ve+/vVzvv71+JHkyeuq4kFpqHe+/vTDvv73vv71e77+977+9aO+/ve+/vXPnp4ZeBmXvv71T77+977+9Jlfvv73vv73ClO+/ve+/vTYK
```

How can I extract the private key from it? What is the format?

The ultimate goal is to implement the following methods:

```js
class TorV3 {
  /**
   * The same result as Tor.getPublicFromSecret(TorV3.readSecretKey(path))
   * @returns KeyObject
   */
  static readPublicKey(path) {}

  /**
   * @returns KeyObject
   */
  static readSecretKey(path) {}

  /**
   * @returns KeyObject
   */
  static getPublicFromSecret(keyObject) {}
}
```

Comment: Related discussion with some answers https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22663/put-ed25519-keys-in-usable-file-format-for-tor